# Uwp app connection to MySql Server not working

Tags: mysql, uwp

I made a uwp app to connect to a mysql server and show data, it work perfectly when debug but when i install the app into another computer it shows me the error message Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts, this my connection string:

```
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;" +
                                                                "Database=database;" +
                                                                "Uid=root;" +
                                                                "Pwd=password;" +
                                                                "SslMode=Preferred"))
```

I already enabled the capabilities privateNetworkClientServer, InternetClien&Server and Enterprise Authenticacion.
This problem it's only when i install the app into another computer, i tried changing the server name to localhost but still not working.
I am missing something?

Comment: When you install the software on other clients, then do you install mysql along with your application or do you have a central database? If the latter, then the connection string should point to the central mysql instance, not to localhost. You should also disclose the proper error message you are getting, not just that something does not work.

Comment: @Shadow sorry, error message only says Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts, i clean install the mysql server with the default port and root username, i create a local database for test, the database name and user password are also the same

Comment: The cannot connect error message indicates that either mysql is not running, listens on another port, or something prevents the client from connecting to the database. You need to figure out which is the case.

Comment: @Shadow mysql service is running, i just changed the port and it still not working :(

Comment: I'm sorry, but cannot help you any further as I cannot see your system.

Comment: Since you are accessing the localhost, you could try to [Enabling loopback for a UWP application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/loopback#enabling-loopback-for-a-uwp-application) in that device

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT thank you so much¡¡¡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for anyone with the same problem, you need to enable Loopback for you uwp app, i found this example "https://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/912-windows-10-uwp-apps-can-t-connect-to-local-ip-loopback-restriction",

you need to find your Package Family Name by running the following in powershell:

"Get-AppxPackage"

then run "CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n="YourPackageFamilyName",

also i change my connection string like this:

using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(@"Host=localhost;UserName=root;Password=password;Database=database;"))